Porque no se actualizan las imagenes de tkinter en un bucle while en python
Estoy intentando hacer una función para mi ajedrez en la que pueda jugar una partida mi algoritmo contra si mismo. Cuando ejecuto el código no se actualizan las imagenes a pesar de que pasa cada jugada por la linea de código de self.mostrarImagenes(). Como puedo hacer para que se muestren después de cada movimiento y no al acabar la partida, porque ahora se actualiza el tablero una vez ha hecho todos los movimientos y se ha acabado la partida.
    def IAvsIA(self,multiplicador):
        while (self.jaqueMate == False) or (self.tablas == False):
            jugada = self.mejorMovimientoIA(multiplicador)
            print(jugada)
            self.afegirHistorial()
            self.tablero[jugada[1][0]][jugada[1][1]] = self.tablero[jugada[0][0]][jugada[0][1]]
            self.tablero[jugada[0][0]][jugada[0][1]] = '--'
            self.comprobarPeonAReina()
            self.cambiarJugador()
            juego.mostrarImagenes()
            self.comprobarJaqueMate()
            self.comprobarJaqueReyBlanco()
            if (self.jaqueReyBlanco == True) and (self.jaqueMate == False):
                messagebox.showinfo('Escacs','Escac al Rei Blanc',parent=juego.ventana)
            self.comprobarTablas()
            multiplicador = -multiplicador


Hola, eso te pasa porque estás bloquendo el mainloop al llamar a ese método  y éste no puede  actualizar ni responder a eventos congelando la app hasta que el método retorna y el mainloop puede proseguir. Mucho cuidado con cualquier ciclo, llamada a función o código en general que se ejecute en el hilo principal y que tarde en retornar, mientras se ejecuta, el mainloop no podrá hacerlo.

O usas mecanismos como after() y callbacks para substituir tu ciclo o mueves el código a otro hilo dejando el principal solo para modificar elementos de la app (jamás modifiques nada de la interfaz desde otro hilo que no sea el principal, pasa información de forma segura entre los hilos y actuializa la app solo desde el hilo principal, el que ejecuta el mainloop).

Tienes problemas con la función mostrarImagenes(), pero no muestras el código de dicha función.

Por cierto, no tiene que ver con el problema, pero no compares valores boleanos con True/False usando los operadores de comparación, en vez de hacer esto: while (self.jaqueMate == False) or (self.tablas == False): es mucho más legible y eficiente while not self.jaqueMate or not self.tablas: o en tu if dentro del ciclo: if self.jaqueReyBlanco and not self.jaqueMate:
